# использование return в функциях

Tags: javascript

коллеги, помогите начинающему разработчику, я уже убил полдня пытаясь уловить суть ретёрна. Читаю документацию вроде бы всё понятно, но суть ускользает.
Ретёрн возвращает результат функции, но например в этом простом коде если я убираю ретёрн, мне функция возвращает то что мне нужно. вопрос - Зачем он тогда нужен? если без него мне тоже все что нужно возвращается?)

```
let a = 2;
let b = 3;


function sumNumbers () {
    return console.log(a+b);
}

sumNumbers();
```

Comment: А зачем Вы возвращаете `console.log()`? `console.log()` просто выводит сообщение в консоль.

Comment: В вашем примере вы получите undefined, т.к. console.log() возвращает undefined. Уберите console из функции и выведете результат ее работы `function sumNumbers () { return a+b; } console.log(sumNumbers())`

Comment: ты путаешь "возвращает" и "показывает на экране". У тебя функция показывает на экране И возвращает результат ``console.log()`` (это СОВСЕМ НЕ ТО, ЧТО БУДЕТ ВЫВЕДЕНО НА ЭКРАН). После того, как ты уберешь return, то останется просто "показывает на экране", что ты и наблюдаешь.

Answer (score 2):

### Объяснение

То, что `a + b` печатается в консоль, ещё не значит, что функция возвращает нужное вам значение. Чтобы проверить, сделаем так:

```js
function sumNumbers() {
  return console.log(2 + 3);
}

let result = sumNumbers();
console.log(result);
```

В консоль выводится `5` и `undefined`. 5 выводится, потому что мы писали `console.log(2 + 3)`, а `undefined` - потому что `console.log` не возвращает значения.

### Более хорошее объяснение

Чтобы лучше понять, как работает `return` скажу так:
То значение, которое получается справа от `return` занимает место вызова функции после его выполнения. К примеру:

```js
function foo1() {
  return 1 + 2;
}

function foo2() {
  console.log(foo1());
  return;
}

foo2();
```

**Что произойдет, когда программа объявит функции `foo1`, `foo2` и вызовет `foo2`?**
Конечно все происходит немного иначе, чем я сейчас покажу, но для ясности представим так. Там, где вызвана функция встают инструкции в теле функции. То есть после простого преобразования получим:

```js
function foo1() {
  return 1 + 2;
}

{
  console.log(foo1());
  return;
}
```

Дальше, в `log` так же вызвана функция. Эту часть так же разберем:

```js
{
  console.log(
    {
      return 1 + 2;
    }
  );
  return;
}
```

Теперь вызовов больше нет. Начинаются выполнения инструкций. Вместо `1 + 2` у нас встает `3`. Получается `return 3`. А как уже сказал, значение справа от `return` встает место функции. То есть получаем:

```js
{
  console.log(3);
  return;
}
```

Дальше `console.log(3);` выводит в консоль 3 и ставит свое возвращаемое значение, а у нее отсутствует возвращаемое значение. Если значение отсутствует, то можно считать, что значение - `undefined`. То есть отсутствие значения и `undefined` это одно и то же. Значит получим:

```js
{
  undefined;
  return;
}
```

а в консоли 3. А так как `undefined` из себя не представляет инструкцию, то его выполнение ни к чему не приводит.
Дальше `return;`. И у `return` справа отсутствует значение, значит после выполнения функции на его месте так же будет стоять `undefined`. И этот `undefined` так же ничего не сделает, так что мы получим всего лишь `3` в консоли.

Comment: Яснее я не в силах объяснить. Я тут сыграл роль интерпретатора и попробовал объяснить максимально пошагово.

Answer (score 0):

> если я убираю ретёрн, мне функция возвращает то что мне нужно

Нет, функция вернёт `undefined`. Просто этого не видно, т.к. возвращаемым значением в коде никак не оперируется. А если написать

```
console.log(sumNumbers());
```

то в консоли будет ещё выведена эта строчка.

---

В текущем случае работа что с `return`, что без него одинакова только по одной причине: в внутри исполняется функция `console.log`, которая печатает информацию в консоль, т.е. в некий output. А если бы внутри было бы написано например `return a+b` то никакого результата бы видно не было бы, до тех пор, пока этот самый результат где-либо не отобразить.

Answer (score 0):

Возврат значения, это то, что **останется на месте функции после** её выполнения. В вашем примере console.log - ***печать результата в вывод консоли***, он к возврату значения отношения не имеет.

Другой пример, есть обычные переменные, которым можно присвоить результат.

```
let a = 10;
let b = "Hello";
```

Вопрос, что будет записано в переменную `c` результате следующего кода?

```
let c = sumNumbers();
```

**Примеры:**

```
function sumNumbers() { return 10; }
let c = sumNumbers(); // let c = sumNumbers() превратится в let c = 10
```

---

```
function sumNumbers() { return "Hello"; }
let c = sumNumbers(); // let c = sumNumbers() превратится в let c = "Hello"
```

---

```
function sumNumbers() { return [1,2,3]; }
let c = sumNumbers(); // let c = sumNumbers() превратится в let c = [1,2,3]
```

---

**Далее**, функция без return возвращает undefined и сама функция console.log() возвращает undefined, поэтому код:

```
function sumNumbers() { return console.log("ok"); }
let c = sumNumbers(); // let c = sumNumbers() превратится в let c = undefined
```

и код

```
function sumNumbers() { console.log("ok"); }
let c = sumNumbers(); // let c = sumNumbers() превратится в let c = undefined
```

одинаковы, их не имеет смысла рассматривать как возвращаемое значение.

**Или другой пример**

```
function isTrue() { return true; }
if (isTrue()) { console.log("ok"); }
```

превратится в

```
if (true) { console.log("ok"); }
```

Поэтому просто представьте, что возвращаемое значение - результат, который останется в коде на месте функции, после её выполнения.